# Spring Boot create .jar file (Maven)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I did not want to ask this question but I tried all the possible solutions on the StackOverFlow. With all the codes I tried the problem was:

[image]

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ahmetbesli</groupId>
    <artifactId>nobet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>nobetci</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am trying to create the jar file with Intellij build artifacts.

I tried to add maven plugin for creating jar file.
I tried to define the mainClass also. But it didn't work.

[spring-boot Maven: How to create executable jar with main class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584533/spring-boot-maven-how-to-create-executable-jar-with-main-class)

[Create Jar of maven spring boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226654/create-jar-of-maven-spring-boot-project)

[Build jar and run spring boot from cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650732/build-jar-and-run-spring-boot-from-cmd)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This: `<version>RELEASE</version>` will not work...remove this because you are using a parent ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should NOT use task jar in IntelliJ like that:
[image]

Instead, we can build jar by this command: `./mvnw clean package`

And start service as usual:  `java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Update: Also can use package in IntelliJ:
[image]

Comment: which command can also be executed from within IntelliJ by using the package command from the lifecycle options.